# Programatically created Spree order items not displaying in admin interface

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I have a Spree-based program where customers are able to order products to be delivered on specified days. I am attempting to override the order creation logic to create multiple orders with the correct products.

The method that handles the form post looks like:

```
class OrderController < ApplicationController
  include Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::Auth
  include Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::Order
  include Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::Common

  ⋮

  def process_order
    params[:order].each do |index, order|
      products = []
      order[:product_id].each do |index, id|
        products << Spree::Product.find(id) if id and not id.empty?
      end
      if products.any?
        populator = Spree::OrderPopulator.new current_order(create_order_if_necessary: true), current_currency
        current_order.update_attribute :delivery_date, Date.parse(order[:date])
        products.each do |product|
          variant = Spree::Variant.find_by product_id: product.id
          populator.populate({ products: { product_id: product.id, variant_id: variant.id }, quantity: 1 })
        end
      end
    end
    redirect_to main_path
  end
end
```

I pulled the code pretty much verbatim from the [Spree source](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/2-1-stable/frontend/app/controllers/spree/orders_controller.rb#L51). An order is created and the order.products method works. When I view the order in the admin interface, however, there is a price, but no products. If I add a product through the admin interface, then it shows up with the count including the ones added programatically.

If I complete the order through the admin interface, all the products show up in the completed order.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should approach this from the order standpoint. But rather from the shipping side of things. The user still only has one order regardless of shippping parameters. Each order has payments, and a checkout statemachine that is designed to take an order to the complete state.

Creating multiple orders is going to be a headache, because then you'll also have to segregate payments and shipments and the rest. I would suggest looking into the shipment logic and how shipments can be split and modified for one order. This way the user pays once, only has one order and one receipt, and you don't clutter your backend with orders and fight the uphill battle to get orders to do something they aren't intended for. You can find an introduction to shipping here: http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/shipments.html

Specifically the section on split shipments, but the rest of it is a great read too.